# AMM Polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve the equation:

$x^7+7px^5+14p^2x^3+7p^3x+q=0$

I've tried obvious things like factorization or maybe guessing a solution.

I'd appreciate a solution not too far from high school level.

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$? This equation will only have a solution for certain values of $q$

Comment: Do you seek solutions over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: P and q are real numbers and yes I seek solutions over R.

Comment: Equation becomes almost homogeneous if you set $p=kx^2$. See what you get then.